# Is it possible to feed sound from bluetooth source through phone to bluetooth headset?

Tags: bluetooth

We use 2 way radios for communication at work. It's often difficult to hear the radio over background noise, so I ordered a bluetooth adapter to plug into the radio to go to an earpiece so I can hear the radio better. I already often wear a bluetooth headset connected to my phone to make phone calls or listen to music when appropriate. What I want to know is would it be possible to link the radio adapter to my phone, and then route the radio sound to the headset linked to the phone, so that I could both make phone calls and talk on the radio with the same headset?
I have an S21 ultra, and the two bluetooth headsets I have are an aftershockz trek air or an axil gs extreme if that makes any difference.

Comment: Some headsets support being paired with to sources at the same time. And switch between both. I think it is called "Bluetooth multipoint [pairing]" .

Comment: I was under the impression that the multipoint would put a priority on the devices, and while it would be connected to two devices, it would only recive sound from the higher priority device?